# Javascript Create Object from Array

Tags: javascript

I really don't understand javascript objects so I'm looking for some help.

I'm playing around drawing lines on google maps, and have the following object:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
  {lat:  53.644578570762484, lng: -2.7243996085112427},
  {lat:  53.6444989, lng: -2.7243514999999996},
  {lat:  53.6444989, lng: -2.7243514999999996},
  {lat:  53.644487771144469, lng: -2.7243445563265229},
  {lat:  53.644059369772329, lng: -2.7240772650391825},
  {lat:  53.644055277360415, lng: -2.7240747116998691}
];
```

This works fine.

What I'd like to do however is create an object like this dynamically.

I have a list of latitudes and longitudes in an array, how do I create an object like the above?

```
var newFlightPath = [];

for (i = 0; i < myLatLngs.length; ++i) {

  //add the lat and lng to newFlightPath somehow?

}
```

Comment: How does your `myLatLngs` array look like?

Comment: `newFlightPath.push( ... );`

Comment: The object you have above **is** a list of latitudes and longitudes in an array!

Comment: is `myLatLngs` an array of arrays?

Comment: I don't quite get the downvotes. considering how objects and arrays work in javascript, it gets pretty confusing.

Comment: @TimothyGroote The OP *hasn't shown* their array, so the question is basically impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the array "myLatLngs" is structured like this: [0 => lat, 1 => lng]. In this case you can just push the objects to your "newFlightPath" array like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < myLatLngs.length; ++i) {
    var obj = {lat: myLatLngs[i][0], lng: myLatLngs[i][1]};
    newFlightPath.push(obj);
}
```

or even more simple:

```
for (i = 0; i < myLatLngs.length; ++i) {
    newFlightPath.push({lat: myLatLngs[i][0], lng: myLatLngs[i][1]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of json objects. You can just loop over `myLatLngs` and push its value in `newFlightPath`

since you have not provided any information regarding, so expecting that myLatLngs is an array of json objects with key as `latitude` & `longitude`

Also use array `forEach`

```
var newFlightPath = [];
myLatLngs.forEach(function(item){
  newFlightPath.push({
   lat:item.latitude,
   lng:item.longitude
})
})
```